# If a customer emails twice with exactly the same email, creating two cases, how do I close the second?

Tags: salesforce, apex

We have a problem with customers emailing twice at the moment, exactly the same content

Email 1: "Hi, please help with x"

Email 2: "Hi, please help with x"

They often email at nearly the same time

How could I close a customer's first open case, where the description (email subject) matches that of an already open case?

I don't think that this is possible through workflows as you'd have to do a lookup on the account's open cases and return the latest one

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option that you could employ is to create a field that is the concatenation (via workflow) of the subject and description and account (dont want to close a case if two cases have the same details from two separate users) and mark that field as unique.  Then the new record would not be created.  Just a thought.

Comment: This is a very smart way of achieving this - thanks. I'll do some testing